# How can I get some padding on table cells in bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I added CSS bootstrap to a rails4 application. This seems to have set the padding on table cells to 0, leaving text crammed against the border. When I tried to add some border-spacing, the text inside the cells wrapped instead of the the table growing to accomodate the text. Here's what I'm trying to fix:

[image: Here's what 'crowded' looks like.]

As far as code goes, here's the HAML that generates the HTML, using the bootstrap classes.

```
%table.table-striped.table-bordered
  %thead
    %tr.header
      %th Date
      %th Name
      %th Reading
      %th Reader
      %th Comments
  %tbody
    - @readings.each do |reading|
      %tr
        %td= reading.date
        %td= reading.name
        %td= reading.reading
        %td= reading.reader.nil? ? '(unassigned)' : reading.reader.name
        %td= reading.comments
        %td= link_to 'Show', reading_path(reading)
        %td= link_to 'Edit', edit_reading_path(reading)
```

According to Chrome 'inspect element', someone has put

```
media="all"
td, th {
    padding: 0;
}
```

into my application.css, but that occurs nowhere in *my* source, so I think it has to be attributed to:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you add some `code` so that we can analyse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add some css...

```
#verses td {
  .padding: 15px;
}
```

In your html.haml I like to add an id to the table so it doesn't effect all tables (unless you want).

```
%table.table-striped.table-bordered#verses
```

There seems to be another css class overriding the bootstrap padding because default is not 0. If you need the other css that is breaking the padding and this is not working, you can use the `!important` and it should work.

```
#verses td {
  .padding: 15px !important;
}
```

Comment: See my edit; something in bootstrap seems to actually set '0'.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is not bootstrap doing that... I have the same @imports in my css.sass, but it's not behaving that way. There must be something else. I have had to completely remove all other css on another project then add module by module until i found it. (wasn't my original project <= disclaimer lol)